# Apache atlas 2.1 configuration connection cassandra backend [help]

Tags: authentication, cassandra, janusgraph, apache-atlas

for a future poc i need to deploy an apache atlas 2.1 stack
but i can't found the parameter for the cassandra backend connection in their documentation.
if anyone got a link or had already made a implementation with password authentication.

this is my current config file if it can help.

```
atlas.graph.storage.backend=cql
atlas.graph.storage.hostname=cassandra
atlas.graph.storage.cassandra.keyspace=JanusGraph

atlas.graph.storage.clustername=cassandra
atlas.graph.storage.port=9042

atlas.EntityAuditRepository.impl=org.apache.atlas.repository.audit.CassandraBasedAuditRepository
atlas.EntityAuditRepository.keyspace=atlas_audit
atlas.EntityAuditRepository.replicationFactor=1

atlas.graph.index.search.backend=solr
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.mode=cloud
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=zookeeper:2181
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-connect-timeout=60000
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.zookeeper-session-timeout=60000
atlas.graph.index.search.solr.wait-searcher=true

atlas.graph.index.search.max-result-set-size=150

atlas.notification.embedded=false
atlas.data=${sys:atlas.home}/data/kafka

atlas.notification.create.topics=true
atlas.notification.replicas=1
atlas.notification.topics=ATLAS_HOOK,ATLAS_ENTITIES
atlas.notification.log.failed.messages=true
atlas.notification.consumer.retry.interval=500
atlas.notification.hook.retry.interval=1000

atlas.enableTLS=false

atlas.authentication.method.kerberos=false
atlas.authentication.method.file=true

atlas.authentication.method.ldap.type=none

atlas.authentication.method.file.filename=${sys:atlas.home}/conf/users-credentials.properties


atlas.rest.address=http://localhost:21000

atlas.audit.hbase.tablename=apache_atlas_entity_audit
atlas.audit.zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=1000
atlas.audit.hbase.zookeeper.quorum=atlas-zookeeper:2181

atlas.server.ha.enabled=false
atlas.authorizer.impl=simple
atlas.authorizer.simple.authz.policy.file=atlas-simple-authz-policy.json
atlas.rest-csrf.enabled=true
atlas.rest-csrf.browser-useragents-regex=^Mozilla.*,^Opera.*,^Chrome.*
atlas.rest-csrf.methods-to-ignore=GET,OPTIONS,HEAD,TRACE
atlas.rest-csrf.custom-header=X-XSRF-HEADER

atlas.metric.query.cache.ttlInSecs=900
```

#########  Gremlin Search Configuration  #########

#Set to false to disable gremlin search.
atlas.search.gremlin.enable=false

theexact issue is :

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host cassandra/172.20.180.174:9042: Host cassandra/xx.xx.xx.xx:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into the [JanusGraph documentation](http://storage.username) for that. According to it, there are two properties there: `storage.username` and `storage.password` that could be used prefixed by `atlas.graph.storage.username`: `atlas.graph.` & `atlas.graph.storage.password`

Comment: I've found it during the week end, thanks for your help.

Comment: https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.4/basics/janusgraph-cfg/#storage if someone want a link in the future

Comment: hi @Alex Ott: I am trying to do same setup on Openshift , with given setting I am able to see janusgraph keyspace created in Cassandra but Atlas server is not coming up and throwing same exception as yours. There is open bug for the same on Atlas , Do you have any idea to resolve it
[link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ATLAS-3993)

Comment: I’m not sure about openshift - some configs may not be available